# How to create a key shortcut to select the next sequential object from a dropdown box in Plotly graph using Python?

Tags: python, callback, plotly

I have a Plotly graph with an updatemenu dropdown box to select different data series. I would like to create a key shortcut to select the next sequential data series from the dropdown box instead of manually selecting it.

Here is the code I have so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Generate random data
num_rows = 100
num_cols = 4
df_stocks = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(num_rows, num_cols), columns=['Stock A', 'Stock B', 'Stock C', 'Stock D'])

# Create plot
fig = go.Figure()

for column in df_stocks.columns.to_list():
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x = df_stocks.index,
            y = df_stocks[column],
            name = column
        )
    )

# Add update menu
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(
        active=0,
        buttons=list(
            [dict(label = 'All',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [True, True, True, True]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Stock A',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [True, False, False, False]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Stock B',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, True, False, False]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Stock C',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, False, True, False]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
             dict(label = 'Stock D',
                  method = 'update',
                  args = [{'visible': [False, False, False, True]},
                          {'showlegend':True}]),
            ])
        )
    ])

fig.show()
```

How can I modify this code to add a keypress event callback to the graph that will select the next sequential data series from the updatemenu dropdown box when a key is pressed?

Comment: true callbacks aren't supported in plotly (notice that all of the traces have to be preloaded). callbacks are supported in `plotly-dash`, but key shortcuts would require using the `dash-extension` library, as discussed [here](https://github.com/plotly/dash/issues/723). i can write up a sample solution for you if you're interested

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please provide a sample solution or guide me on how to implement this feature? Thank you...